# Prevent Bootstrap from Adding 'open' class to dropdown menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap v3.3.7 and would like to stop Bootstrap from adding the `open` class when someone clicks on parent menu item. I simply want the hover action but not to keep the menu expanded on click. Every post I've seen are of people trying to add the class, but none the other way around.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe how simple the solution was... simply remove `data-toggle="dropdown"` and the menu will only work on hover.